# Redirect Form User When Submit Based On Radio Selection Only

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I have very low knowledge on coding so picking up the basics as i go along.

During my multiple page form i have 4 "radio" type selections where the end user has to select at least 1 to proceed with the form. What i am trying to do is have the form Redirect the user to the specific page relation to the radio input they selected when they **submit** the form.

I Have watched you tube videos and read loads of old posts all day and everything i try seems to not work.

Im not sure if javascript, jquery or php would be best using the if or isset statement, Due to my knowledge im not upto date with the right search phrases to use in order to find the correct method so after 14 hours of trying im having to seek your expertise!

Any simple way would be adequate  and extremely helpful and for that im hoping someone can help me out on this.

for example the 4 radio selections would go to:

```
<input class="form-radio" type="radio" id="hbs" name="options" value="hbs" />  ==>  page1.php
<input class="form-radio" type="radio" id="bs"  name="options" value="bs"  />  ==>  page2.php
<input class="form-radio" type="radio" id="pvr" name="options" value="pvr" />  ==>  page3.php
<input class="form-radio" type="radio" id="epc" name="options" value="epc" />  ==>  page4.php
```

I need the code to only redirect the user when he has clicked on submit, The reason for this is there are multiple fields within the form on the same page as the radio selections.

Thanks

Comment: The redirect header is probably what y ou are looking for: http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Comment: Nevermind... there is a simpler solution. I wrote it in an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can redirect a to a specific page via `header('Location: url');` in php.

Here is an example matching your request :

```
<?php
$value_to_page = array(
    "hbs" => 'page1.php',
    "bs"  => 'page2.php',
    "pvr" => 'page3.php',
    "epc" => 'page4.php',
);
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    // process other fields like $_POST['some-other']
    if(isset($_POST['options']) && isset($value_to_page[$_POST['options']])){
        header('Location: '.$value_to_page[$_POST['options']]);
        return;
    }
} ?>

<form method="post">
    <input type="text" name="some-other" />
    <input class="form-radio" type="radio" id="hbs" name="options" value="hbs" />
    <input class="form-radio" type="radio" id="bs"  name="options" value="bs"  />
    <input class="form-radio" type="radio" id="pvr" name="options" value="pvr" />
    <input class="form-radio" type="radio" id="epc" name="options" value="epc" />
    <button type="submit" name="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Excellent work, That works better than anything ive tried so far! the only problem is the code is sending all 4 options to page1.php and the reason for it is because name is set to name="options" on all 4 radio selections. i can not change the name as it affects the way the page works. Is there another way round that?  Thanks

Comment: The redirect is not based on the name of the field but on his value. And this is the variable which does it : `$value_to_page`, if hbs, bs, pvr and epc are not your real value, just update them in `$value_to_page` and you would have a working copy

Comment: Perfect, I shortened the values when posting the question to look more clean. It works like a charm and hopefully further people with my same problem will see your answer and credit you for this as i do not have enough rep just yet to +1 your answer! Thank you so much for taking the time to assist, its been very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution might be to require_once the code of the page you want for the results of the POST as shown (place this at the top of your php file above any HTML):

```
<?php

switch ($_POST["options"]) {
    case "hbs":
        require_once("page1.php");
        break;
    case "bs":
        require_once("page2.php");
        break;
    case "pvr":
        require_once("page3.php");
        break;
    case "epc":
        require_once("page4.php");
}

die();

?>
```

Comment: Ok. If you have this PHP code in the same file as your HTML you should put a die(); at the bottom below the switch.

Comment: Just tried that and does not seem to work. my <form action="endpage.php" method="post" id="form"> is set as normal so im trying to get the code i add to the page to overide the form submission page based on the radio box they select during filling the form out. so for example they select radio named (hbs) and go on to fill their name and details out then at the bottom click submit.. They form will send them to hbs-page.php and if they selected (bs) on the radio selection instead they would have been sent to bs-page.php and so on... thanks for taking time to help out, its appreciated.

Comment: i put the php at the top of the page above all the html but never used the die function.

Comment: Thats crazy. I tested it on my system before posting. Can I ask what happened?

Comment: i managed to get it to work trixtur but with the require once i believe its messing the layout of the page up and the form action page is loading with the page1.php? does this sound about right, im going to do some further testing now.. and see what i can do as i am only a beginner lol

Comment: Yeah... the reason you needed the die(); immediately after the switch and put the PHP before your HTML was so that it wouldn't mess up your page. Sorry I didn't specify that at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is a good question, it is not hard though, follow using jQuery, you too [can see it working in jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/deFreitas/z5a63vvw/5/) (will not work properly in jsfiddle for security questions, but try it in your machine ):

```
<form id="myForm">
    <input class="form-radio" type="radio" id="hbs" checked="true" name="options" value="hbs"  page="page1.php" />  ==>  page1.php
    <input class="form-radio" type="radio" id="bs"  name="options" value="bs" page="page2.php"  />  ==>  page2.php
    <input class="form-radio" type="radio" id="pvr" name="options" value="pvr" page="page3.php" />  ==>  page3.php
    <input class="form-radio" type="radio" id="epc" name="options" value="epc" page="page4.php" />  ==>  page4.php
    <button type="submit">send</button>
</form>

<script>
    $(function(){
       $("#myForm").submit(function(e){
           var page = $(this).find("input[name=options]:checked").attr("page");
           this.action = page;       
       });
    });
</script>
```